# Mirror d3 graph horizontally in JavaScript/html

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to flip a graph in JS without changing the axis. 
JavaScript isn't my specialty and after googling for 4 hours I'm starting to think it isn't possible. 
Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

d3.json("data2.json", function(error, heatmap) {
  var dx = heatmap[0].length,
      dy = heatmap.length;

  // Fix the aspect ratio.
  // var ka = dy / dx, kb = height / width;
  // if (ka < kb) height = width * ka;
  // else width = height / ka;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, dx])
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, dy])
      .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([null, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120])
      .range(["#FFFFFF", "#FF0000", "#FF9933", "#FFFF00", "#99FF33", "#00FF00"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("top")
      .ticks(20);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("right");

  d3.select("body").append("canvas")
      .attr("width", dx)
      .attr("height", dy)
      .style("width", width + "px")
      .style("height", height + "px")
      .call(drawImage);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .call(removeZero);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .call(removeZero);


  function drawImage(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
        image = context.createImageData(dx, dy);     


    for (var y = 0, p = -1; y < dy; ++y) {
      for (var x = 0; x < dx; ++x) {
        var c = d3.rgb(color(heatmap[y][x]));
        image.data[++p] = c.r;
        image.data[++p] = c.g;
        image.data[++p] = c.b;
        image.data[++p] = 255;
      }
    }

    context.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
  }

  function removeZero(axis) {
    axis.selectAll("g").filter(function(d) { return !d; }).remove();
  }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're actually not really using D3 for the part of the code that makes the image itself.  In the nested loops, when you're manually producing the bitmap image, you can just traverse the data in reverse.  Instead of indexing the row `heatmap[y]` directly on `x`, you should index on `dx - x - 1`, the column number counting from the right.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkw1bzrm/)

As an aside, it seems a little strange to be mixing SVG and canvas drawing techniques here.  Depending on how much data you're showing, it may be valuable to draw the heatmap with SVG as well, which would allow you to use just a single API to draw the chart and would enable interactions as well.  Alternatively, you could go for drawing the whole thing on canvas, if a static image is more appropriate, for instance if the scale of data is massive.

Comment: The in- and output of the graph are going to be quite massive, it's scientific data. My only requirements are that:

- Input and output must be .json
- Output must be horizontally mirrored. (e.g. up becomes down :)) 
- In the future, we're trying to make the graph interactive with a tooltip displaying the value.

Is changing to 'all-canvas' a better option in this case? And what's the best way the do this?

Comment: If you'd like to provide tooltips on hover your life as a developer will be much easier if you render the chart with SVG, since individual SVG elements have regular DOM hover behavior.  To get the same effect on canvas will require that you calculate the relative mouse position and will likely have cross-browser issues to untangle.

Comment: Also, I believe the term for mirroring when up and down are switched (i.e., over the horizontal axis) is generally vertical mirrored.  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18082/horizontal-and-vertical-flipping-mirroring